# How to create an unique id for each attachment image in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, unique-id

Im trying to create a function for thumbs rotation in wordpress I get everything working but Im stack on the unique id which is required in my js file.

So this is my php function but it doesn't show randomly a different id it shows allways the same id for all thumbnails created.

```
function thumb_rotation(){
    global $post;
    $uniqueID = 'thumb_';
    $characters = array_merge(range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(0, count($characters)-1);
    $uniqueID .= $characters[$rand];
    }
        $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_rotator', true );
        $size = 'thumb-video';
        if( $images ):
            foreach( $images as $image ):
                        echo '<span class="mb">';
              echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, $size, false, array('title' => '', 'alt' => '', 'class' => 'mvThumb', 'id' => $uniqueID));
                        echo '</span>';
                endforeach;
            endif;
}
```

Any idea what Im doing wrong here?
Thank You!

Comment: Does it have to be an int, you can use `uniqid($prefix, $entropy)` if not.  It doesn't 100% grantee uniqueness though http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php but neither does `mt_rand`, which is the same as `rand` now (PHP v7.1)

Comment: I have 7.0 in localhot and worked but im not sure about 7.1 thankyou I'll try that

Comment: I have 5.3+ locally ( 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 7, 7.1, 7.2), but I also have like 5 browsers,  Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge, Safari, But I also have Mysql, MongoDB, Cassandra, Sphinx, MSSQL, bla bla... MariaDB.  Lets not forget PHP, Python, Pearl, .Net, Java too.  Man I have lot of stuff.  Sorry.

Comment: I changed mt_rand ro rand as you suggested its working too thankyouBut Im going to open a new topic for the same code since I can't figure it out.

Comment: You already have your unique ID, `$image` it looks like this should be the image ID from the worpress DB.  `function wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, ...)`  So what I would do is take that number and just add `"image_{$image)"` Javascript ID's can't/shouldn't start with a number.  So this will be like `image_407`, `image_679` etc. Based on the Primary Key for the image.

Comment: No I got it under inside the foreach loop and this one worked but my problem is different I canoot rotate the thumbs  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585779/preview-images-thumbnails-rotation-on-mouse-hover-with-jquery-on-wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id generator is outside of your images loop.

Comment: :) omg thanks need to wait 7 minutes to set this resolved you are correct thankyou and sorry for posting this question was a big mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have a UniqueID, you don't realize it.

I think at least, I don't work much with wordpress but the definition for this WP function.

```
 wp_get_attachment_image( int $attachment_id, string|array $size = 'thumbnail', bool $icon = false, string|array $attr = '' )
```

Looks like the first argument is the Image's ID from the Database. In your code you have this as

```
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($image,  ..)
```

So if I am right about this then `$image` should be a Integer and it should be the Primary Key for the image, which by design is already a unique ID.

Now one thing to mention is in Javascript/HTML element ID's should not start with a number.  I am not sure if this is still true but I remember it was that way some time ago (maybe I last checked 8 years ago on that, lol), so I never start them with numbers.  So what I suggest is to just prefix that ID. like this:

```
  $imageID = "image_{$image}";
```

So that if the `$image` value is 345 which is also it's Pkey from the Database then your ID for the element would be `image_345`.  And because this is the Primary Key, no other image will ever have that same ID (unless it's the same image).  That is if I am thinking about it all the right way.  As I said I don't dig too much into wordpress.

We have a handful of wordpress sites, but that is more of a convenience for our non-programer content creators.  Then any of our sites that require heavy lifting on the programming side, we just template the front end with wordpress, use the Wp header and footer on the backend stuff.  And then pull the content we want for the backend from the post by the slug and mix that with our custom CodeIgniter setup.  So the majority of our programing is done outside of wordpress, but is still themed by wordpress if that makes sense.

Sorry that justification for my lack of wordpress ability was a bit longer then it should have been.  We find either we need almost no custom code, or we need a ton of it. In which case it's far easier to do it outside of WP.

Comment: its resolved however thankyou for your answer but it generates a random ID for each thumbnail now my mistake was because it was outside of the foreach loop.Everything is fine now.Thank You!

Comment: Randomness is not a guarantee of uniqueness.  If `$image` is the primary key, you should definitely use it as it's `100%` going to be unique.  As far as what answer you accept, frankly I could care less about the answer points (AKA. you can leave the other accepted even if you choose to use this).  But from a functional and a robustness aspect using the PKey would be far superior.